# Why does the Canvas context's save/restore method fail to remove a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

HTML Canvas context's save/restore method not working.

There is a simple example of drawing a rectangle on canvas an then trying to restore the previous state, which actually does not work. What am I doing wrong with this ?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Draw red rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

// Save the current state
ctx.save();

// Add blue rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillRect(70, 10, 50, 50);

// Restore the saved state
ctx.restore();  // this should remove blue rectangle
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [save](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) method stores the drawing state, this doesn't necessarily include drawn shapes.
The drawing state is (as stated on MDN):

> The drawing state that gets saved onto a stack consists of:
>
> - The current transformation matrix.
> - The current clipping region.
> - The current dash list.
> - The current values of the following attributes:
>   strokeStyle, fillStyle, globalAlpha, lineWidth, lineCap, lineJoin,
>   miterLimit, lineDashOffset, shadowOffsetX, shadowOffsetY, shadowBlur,
>   shadowColor, globalCompositeOperation, font, textAlign, textBaseline,
>   direction, imageSmoothingEnabled.

You can see this in action by drawing the same blue square again. You will notice the color is now red, meaning the state has reverted to its original values.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Draw red rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

// Save the current state
ctx.save();

// Add blue rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillRect(70, 10, 50, 50);

// Restore the saved state
ctx.restore();

// Draw "blue" rectangle again
ctx.fillRect(70, 10, 50, 50);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```